# Expo unexpected token in JSON position 0?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I recently started learning React Native. I downloaded expo on my android phone. After running expo init and starting the server I scanned QR code from my phone. I instantly got an error back.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaJWv.jpg)
How do I solve this error?

Comment: try restarting the server and wait for the server to show on the app rather than scanning the bar code.

Comment: Try to restart expo with clear flag too. i.e. https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-clear-the-expo-and-react-native-packager-caches-metro-watchman-haste/1352